# Plugin stops executing code without raising an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently started making a gem for one of my projects, however when it gets to a certain part while running it will just stop executing and go right to the end and returns an empty array. The problem is in the parse_results function

```
def parse_results(result)
  puts result
  result_hash = Hash.new
  result_hash["url"] = result.id
  result_hash["score"] = result.rule_groups["SPEED"].score

  result_hash["rule_results"] = Hash.new
  # it cuts out right as it tries this puts command below, nothing is output
  puts result_hash["rule_results"]["AvoidLandingPageRedirects"].localized_rule_name
  rule_result_names = ["AvoidLandingPageRedirects", "EnableGzipCompression", "LeverageBrowserCaching", "MainResourceServerResponseTime", "MinifyCss", "MinifyHTML", "MinifyJavaScript", "MinimizeRenderBlockingResources", "OptimizeImages", "PrioritizeVisibleContent"]
  rule_result_names.each do |rule|
    puts rule
    result_hash["rule_results"][rule] = Hash.new
    result_hash["rule_results"][rule]["name"] = result.formatted_results.rule_results[rule].localized_rule_name
    result_hash["rule_results"][rule]["impact"] = result.formatted_results.rule_results[rule].rule_impact
    result_hash["rule_results"][rule]["advice"] = result.formatted_results.rule_results[rule].format
  end
  puts result_hash
  return result_hash
end
```

Before this it would cut out when trying to do the `.each` part even though the array is set up fine. Any clue as to why this would be occurring? The url, and score both get set fine. It is getting passed a Json/hash object from Google, which is valid. It was also unusual because these commands work fine when I was debugging with pry, at least the puts command that the code cuts off at now. Let me know if anything else is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes strange errors like these when developing gems is because you're not loading the right version of your gem. Are you sure you're actually loading the latest version of your gem, and not some test code or a previous version, because you forgot to commit the code properly. Methods don't usually stop executing mid stream without an error, unless you're running the method inside an exception handler.

Comment: @Casper As far as I know I haven't updated the version on it at all, just stuck with the default 0.1.0 and have been using that for everything. That does sound like a bug that would happen with it though. I'll try updating the version tomorrow. Is this something that could also happen if I had conflicting versions of dependencies as well?

Comment: What I meant was are you sure your program is loading the gem you think it's loading. But from your other responses it seems that it is loading the correct one. A simple test is to modify your gem and add a line for example  `puts "TEST"` in the code and see if your program prints this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the function calling this one. The given function relies on a batch call to google's apis. It would try to update the result in the block I gave it and would result in errors in this `parse_results` function

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being output because `result_hash["rule_results"]` is an empty hash.

Effectively, this is what's happening:

```
2.2.2 :001 > some = Hash.new
 => {} 
2.2.2 :002 > puts some['foo'].bar
NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for nil:NilClass
```

It's possible that you're not seeing an exception because some piece of your code or the gem's is swallowing the exception and returning an empty array.

Comment: ah @pdoherty926 you're absolutely right for that first puts statement, it should be `result.formatted_results.rule_results["AvoidLandingPageRedirects"]`. But I'm still getting the problem with that line omitted. Do you see anything that would be interfering with the `.each` statement?

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me. I'd recommend making static mutations from within your each loop in order to verify you're starting on solid ground. e.g. `result_hash["rule_results"][rule] = rule`.  Are you rescuing `Exception` or something somewhere that's preventing you from seeing any errors which might be generated by this method?